# Cuantos fragments puedo meter en un activity?

Tags: java, android, activity, fragment, android-drawerlayout

El problema es que tengo una aplicación el cual tiene muchos fragments 10 para ser precisos y un activity,en la activity coloque un drawer layout el cual contiene 10 opciones que te llevan a su respectivo fragment y después tengo pensado poner mas fragments en esa misma activity por eso me pregunto si esta bien o tengo que crear otra segunda activity el cual equilibre la cantidad de fragments que hay en una y ahí surge otro problema si hago otra activity el drawerlayout tengo que copiar y pegarlo y eso no me gusta mucho ya que es código repetido es por eso que necesito ayuda o siempre es mejor tener solo una activity el cual controle todo.

Comment: Podria decirse que no hay limite, pero antes de determinar esto ahora la pregunta es, ¿Deseas agregarlos en un Framelayout o deseas agregarlos mediante transacciones? Te sugiero primeramente revises al teoría relacionada a Fragments https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=es . Realiza tus preguntas en base a [ask], saludos.

Comment: Agrega más de tu código y modifica tu pregunta, te podemos ayudar a estructurar lo que deseas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la documentación no veo límites sobre la cantidad de fragmentos que puede usar, pero, es una buena idea pensar antes de declarar fragmentos, si tienes muchos fragmentos, puede comenzar con problemas sobre la "lógica".

Primero comienza revisando las herramientas de navegación y menús que ofrece `Android`, luego debes saber cuántos fragmentos o actividades necesitas realmente. De esta forma puedes estructurar mejor tu proyecto sin la necesidad de manejar todo por el `Drawer`.